# Question answer generation using BERT embedding and LSTM layer?

Tags: lstm, bert-language-model, nlp-question-answering

How i use the BERT embedding as embedding layer with LSTM for generation quesiton answer ?

I have tried bert embedding but i am not able stack the bert embedding with LSTM in question answer generation problem.
Or we can use any other LLM for embedding with LSTM for question answer generation